# How can I populate more than one zendform?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, foreach, populate

I'm a problem about the population of many zend forms. Let me explain: I need to modified more users at the same time and I wanted to show in a view one populated form (with the old data to modify) for every user that I preaviously selected.
I have this code in my controller:

```
$list = $this->getRequest()->getParam('utenti');
$users=$this->_adminModel->getUsersByName($list);
$data=array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
$i=0;
$data[$i]=array(
'nome'=>$user->nome, 
'cognome'=>$user->cognome,
'email'=>$user->email,
'genere'=>$user->genere,
'nascita'=>$user->nascita,
'username'=>$user->username,
'passwd'=>$user->passwd,
'ripasswd'=>$user->passwd,
'impiego'=>$user->impiego,
'fumatore'=>$user->fumatore,
'telefono'=>$user->telefono,
'role'=>$user->role);
$i++;
$this->view->data= $data;}
```

In the wiew, instead I have:

```
<? foreach($this->data ad $data){
echo $this->myform->populate($data);
}?>
```

The error that I have is:
Warning:Invalid argument supplied for foreach in myview.phtml.
Where am I wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `ad` by `as` in your foreach.